# It takes a lot of time for RecycleView to display items after data is set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Does anyone have an idea why it takes 4 or 5 second for adapter to call onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and other adapter methods after data is set?

Logs

```
12-05 22:37:39.560 26343-26343/com.iteco.specsvyaz D/RecentsAdapter: update data
12-05 22:37:43.660 26343-26343/com.iteco.specsvyaz D/RecentsAdapter: getItemViewType
```

This is How I pass data in fragment

```
adapter.updateData(generateRecentListToShow(it))
```

This is how I set data in my adapter

```
  fun updateData(list: List<RecentModel>) {
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(RecentDiffUtilCallback(this.list, list, currentConference, prevCurrentConference))
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        prevCurrentConference = currentConference
        this.list = list
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","update data")
    }
```

Full code of adapter class

```
class RecentsAdapter(var list: List<RecentModel>,
                     private val onClickListener: (RecentModel) -> Unit,
                     private val onLongClickListener: (RecentModel) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentHolder>(){

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","getItemViewType")
        return list[position].chatType
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecentHolder {
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","onCreateViewHolder")
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recent, parent, false)
        return when(viewType) {
            Const.RoomTypes.PRIVATE -> PrivateChatHolder(itemView)
            Const.RoomTypes.GROUP -> GroupHolder(itemView)
            Const.RoomTypes.ROOM -> RoomHolder(itemView)
            else -> PrivateChatHolder(itemView)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecentHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position], onClickListener, onLongClickListener, currentConference)
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","onBindViewHolder")
    }
    fun updateData(list: List<RecentModel>) {
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(RecentDiffUtilCallback(this.list, list, currentConference, prevCurrentConference))
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        prevCurrentConference = currentConference
        this.list = list
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","update data")
    }

 }
```

Full code of RecentDiffUtilCallback class

```
class RecentDiffUtilCallback internal constructor(private val oldList: List<RecentModel>, private val newList: List<RecentModel>, private val currentConference: ConferenceCallReceived?, private val prevCurrentConference: ConferenceCallReceived?) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","getOldListSize")

        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","getNewListSize")

        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldRecent = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val newRecent = newList[newItemPosition]
        var res = oldRecent._id == newRecent._id
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","areItemsTheSame")

        return res
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldRecent = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val newRecent = newList[newItemPosition]


        val oldCalls = oldList[oldItemPosition].callHistory
        val newCalls = newList[newItemPosition].callHistory
        val oldUserName = oldCalls?.user?.name ?: oldCalls?.room?.name
        val newUserName = newCalls?.user?.name ?: newCalls?.room?.name
        val oldAvatar = oldCalls?.user?.avatar ?: oldCalls?.room?.avatar
        val newAvatar = newCalls?.user?.avatar ?: newCalls?.room?.avatar


        val res = newRecent.lastUpdate == oldRecent.lastUpdate &&
                oldRecent.unreadCount == newRecent.unreadCount &&
                oldRecent.unseenByOtherCount == newRecent.unseenByOtherCount &&
                oldRecent.isMuted == newRecent.isMuted &&
                ((oldRecent.user == null && newRecent.user == null) || oldRecent.user.doNotDisturb == newRecent.user.doNotDisturb)&&
                ((oldRecent.draft == null && newRecent.draft == null) || oldRecent.draft == newRecent.draft)&&
                ((oldRecent.pinned == null && newRecent.pinned == null) || oldRecent.pinned == newRecent.pinned) &&
                ((oldRecent.lastMessage == null && newRecent.lastMessage == null) || oldRecent.lastMessage?.isSent == newRecent.lastMessage?.isSent) &&
                ((oldRecent.user == null && newRecent.user == null) || oldRecent.user.onlineStatus == newRecent.user.onlineStatus) &&
                oldUserName == newUserName && oldAvatar == newAvatar &&
                currentConference == prevCurrentConference &&
                oldCalls?.lastConference?.started == newCalls?.lastConference?.started &&
                oldCalls?.lastConference?.ended == newCalls?.lastConference?.ended &&
                oldCalls?.lastConference?.status == newCalls?.lastConference?.status &&
                oldCalls?.lastConference?.typeDirection == newCalls?.lastConference?.typeDirection
        Log.d("RecentsAdapter","areContentsTheSame")

        return res
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it takes time to calculate the difference using your `calculateDiff` function. Also, I did not see any `notifyDataSetChanged` call in your adapter after you have updated the data.

Comment: @ReazMurshed According to logs, DiffUtill methods are called after adapter methods, so I think it's not the reason


`12-05 23:19:59.520 30401-30401/com.iteco.specsvyaz D/RecentsAdapter: update data

12-05 23:20:05.701 30401-30401/com.iteco.specsvyaz D/RecentsAdapter: getOldListSize
12-05 23:20:05.701 30401-30401/com.iteco.specsvyaz D/RecentsAdapter: getNewListSize`

And as I know, there is no need to call notifyDataSetChanged when using DiffUtill https://blog.mindorks.com/the-powerful-tool-diff-util-in-recyclerview-android-tutorial